# How to remove from DOM or display: none everything except <img> tags?

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have the following markup:

```
<div class="post-body">
  <div class="separator">
    <img src="https://www.example.com/image-01.png" />
  </div>
  <h1>Some heading</h1>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text</p>
  <img src="https://www.example.com/image-02.png" />
  <div class="separator">
    <img src="https://www.example.com/image-03.png" />
    <span>Some text some text some text</span>
  </div>
  <img src="https://www.example.com/image-04.png" />
</div>
```

How can I remove from DOM or `display: none` everything within `<div class="post-body">` except `<img>` tags to render the following output?

```
<div class="post-body">
    <img src="https://www.example.com/image-01.png"/>
    <img src="https://www.example.com/image-02.png"/>
    <img src="https://www.example.com/image-03.png"/>
    <img src="https://www.example.com/image-04.png"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share what is your expected output with both "_remove from DOM or display: none_".

Comment: [How to remove everything within a DIV except for one element?](//stackoverflow.com/a/8737148)

Comment: Just updated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using two line code like:

```
const $imgs = $('.post-body img')
$('.post-body').html($imgs)
```

**DEMO:**

```js
const $imgs = $('.post-body img')
$('.post-body').html($imgs)
```

```css
img{border:1px solid red;width:100px;height:100px;padding:4px;margin-left:5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-body">
  <div class="separator">
    <img src="https://www.example.com/image-01.png" />
  </div>
  <h1>Some heading</h1>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text</p>
  <img src="https://www.example.com/image-02.png" />
  <div class="separator">
    <img src="https://www.example.com/image-03.png" />
    <span>Some text some text some text</span>
  </div>
  <img src="https://www.example.com/image-04.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Worked perfectly. Thank you @palaѕн :)